# Pavucontrol rear behaviour

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio

I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS.

When I use Mozilla Firefox to play videos, Pavucontrol adds a new volumen control, into its GUI, for each new video I see. But the only one control which is really controlling the video audio is the last added (lowest position into the Pavucontrol GUI).

In other words, if I'd play (let's say) 200 videos a day (it doesn't matter whatever the source web page was), I'd get 200 new volumen controls into the Pavucontrol GUI.

When I close Mozilla Firefox, all the Pavucontrol GUI back to the normal status.

Is it a normal behaviour?

If it is not... How can I fix it?

Comment: when a video closes the volume control for it should disappear. Since they are removed when firefox closes, it suggest a bug with firefox or the web site where you are watching the videos.

Comment: I think it is a Firefox bug, because I always use 3 video sites: YouTube, and two chilean broadcasting media, both with its own video service.